# Using mapfragment functionality offline

Tags: android, mapactivity, mapfragment

I am developing a tracking app, so I use the GPS data to draw a route + checkpoints in a canvas. The problem is, I developed zoom/drag+span in a SurfaceView and all the "lat-long to cartesian conversion", but it would be so much easy to do all this stuff if I could use the maps api functionality (with my own overlay).

So my question is, can I use the maps api/MapFragment without internet connection and take advantage of the api functionality? Has any of you done something like this before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to use the maps api v2 without overlay doing this:

```
mMap.setMapType(0);
```

Now I can take advantage of scroll/pan/zoom + location utils from the api without showing an overlay...it's pretty cool :D